Suppressing Step Function warnings about JSONPath expressions
I am using AWS Step Functions to choreograph a workflow that involves calling multiple AWS lambdas.
Some of those lambdas require payloads containing JSONPath expressions, as their implementation uses these expressions to retrieve specific fields from DynamoDb records.
Recently, the step function editor has begun presenting me with warnings to alert me to the presence of these JSONPath expressions, in case I wish the step function platform to evaluate the JSONPath expressions at runtime. I do not. These warnings are false positives.
How can I suppress these warnings on an case-by-case basis?
There are Amazon States Language warnings about your state machine definition. Please review to confirm that the state machine will execute as intended.
The value of 'isAuthorisedFirmFlow' looks like a JSONPath. Instead of 'isAuthorisedFirmFlow', use 'isAuthorisedFirmFlow.$' to evaluate it as a JSONPath at runtime. /States/Try/Branches[0]/States/Application Data Worker/Parameters/Payload/attributes
For more information, see Amazon States Language 


Here is the ASL for the lambda invoke task that is causing these warnings:
    "Application Data Worker": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName.$": "States.Format('gateway-{}-dataprocessor-applicationdata-lambda:$LATEST', $.environment)",
        "Payload": {
          "attributes": {
            "intactApplicationId": "$.intactApplicationId",
            "firmId": "$.entities.applicationFirm.firmId",
            "ARN": "$.intactApplicationReferenceNumber",
            "contactId": "$.entities.applicationContactDetails.contactId",
            "firmName": "$.entities.applicationFirm.name",
            "effectiveDateOfChange": "$.entities.fdaFirmDetails.effectiveDateOfChange",
            "contactFirstName": "$.entities.applicationContactDetails.firstName",
            "contactLastName": "$.entities.applicationContactDetails.lastName",
            "contactEmail": "$.entities.applicationContactDetails.emailAddress",
            "submittedDate": "$.submittedDate",
            "submittedUserId": "$.submittedUserId",
            "registeredName": "$.entities.fdaFirmDetails.name",
            "registeredNameSnapshot": "$.entities.fdaFirmDetailsSnapshot.name",
            "hasARDetailsChecked": "$.entities.fdaFirmDetails.hasARDetailsChecked"
          },
          "applicationId.$": "$.applicationId",
          "userId.$": "$.userId",
          "correlationId.$": "$.correlationId"
        }
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 60,
          "MaxAttempts": 4,
          "BackoffRate": 3
        }
      ],
      "Next": "Intact Application Worker",
      "ResultPath": "$.applicationDataResult",
      "ResultSelector": {
        "applicationData.$": "$.Payload.data"
      }
    },


Would you be able to include the piece of ASL that triggers this false positive?

Hi @JustinCallison, certainly - I've edited the question to include the ASL. Thanks.

AWS recently introduced Validation API so there's no obvious way around it. The best you can do is use some kind of ASL to suppress those, e.g.:

    {
       "intactApplicationId.$": "States.Format('$.intactApplicationId')",
       ...
    }



That's a cunning idea, thanks for the suggestion!
Slightly irksome that it should be necessary, but perhaps less so than seeing the yellow validation warnings.
